# Android Studio, No JVM Installation Found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

I just download Android Studio and installed it on my computer. I previously had installed the JDK Development Kit also (jdk1.8.0_65).

When I try to open the program I get the following error: "*No JVM installation found. Please install a 64-bit JDK. If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer >... etc.*"

I created the variable and pointed it to the location of my JDK and restarted my computer but the same error keeps popping up. What am I missing?

**Computer Specs**

- Windows 7 64bit
- JDK installed: 1.8.0_66-b18

Comment: Are you sure you have installed 64 bit version of JDK?

Comment: Check and see that it is the 64 bit version of JDK, and what is your exact path that you defined to JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Also as per documentation JDK 7 is required. please see https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I went the the Java control panel and it says it is a 32Bit, how do I delete any/all versions of java that I have and which is the 64 bit version? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 64 bit version of JDK, I suspect you are using 32 bit. You can manually uninstall the current version. See [How to uninstall JDK](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_java.xml)

Once this is done install 64 bit JDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you click the correct executable (**studio.exe** or **studio64.exe**) depending on your environment when launching Android Studio, otherwise you might see the message "No JVM Installation Found".